# Laptop touchpad right-click problem Ubuntu 16.04 [Dell Vostro 3568]

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, dell, dell-vostro

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my new Laptop (Dell Vostro 3568) about a week ago. My right-click is working same as the left click.

I am attaching a screenshot of the settings. 
I tried various options, but no result.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the answer [from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957099/dell-vostro-3568-model-ubuntu-17-04-touch-pad-left-and-right-click-behaving-same)?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem initially. After trying out a number of options, I realized that the left and the right buttons serve the same purpose. Maybe, it is a manufacturing defect. To get along, you can fix the problem by setting **right** as the primary button. This way you can use the touchpad for selecting objects and any of the two buttons for getting the pop-menu for these objects.

Comment: Good workaround. But apparently a fix has been found. Have you checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/957831/480481)?