# Dell Vostro 3568 model ubuntu 17.04 touch-pad left and right click behaving same way

Tags: mouse, touchpad, dell-vostro

I'm using Dell Vostro 3568 model, recently installed ubuntu 17.04. My touch-pad left and right click working same way.

If left radio button selected in my settings( All Settings->Mouse & Touchpad->General->Primary button) then left and right click behaving like left click always no matter even I clicked left or right.

If right radio button selected in my settings( All Settings->Mouse & Touchpad->General->Primary button) then left and right click behaving like Right click always no matter even I clicked left or right.

Can some one help me to get this fixed, please?? Thanks in advance.

[image: Left settings]

[image: Right settings]

Comment: try: xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3"

Comment: If will not work, try using xinput list, find your mouse, remember the id, and then write to terminal xinput set-button-map YOURID 1 2 3

Comment: @Raushan [this bugreport for your notebook](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1430586) have two solutions at the very end. It's unclear though if they work for everyone, and whether kernel 4.11 is required. It's better if you try them out, and post as an answer the one that worked for you *(or comment here if none have worked)*.

Comment: doesn't work with 18.04

Comment: I have this problem too. The only files with

Comment: @Kid101 For me, the answer to this problem was with this Ubuntu 18.04 feature https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/

Comment: @JoshuaFox didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 10):

First add the line  `Option "ClickPad" "true"` to the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf` so that the final output looks like:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "ClickPad" "true"
EndSection
```

Then reboot the system. Right click should work fine now.

---

Adapted from [this Red Hat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1430586#c22), as suggested by [Hi-Angel](https://askubuntu.com/users/266507/hi-angel).

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: If this solves your problem, you may consider ["accepting" the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) so others may more easily find it in the future. It's completely fine to accept your own answer :-)

Comment: I apparently have a different touchpad driver on my  Dell Inspiron 7577 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Under /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d, the only files with "touchpad" or similar are here 70-wacom.conf pastebin.com/wsTcdJJV and 40-libinput.conf pastebin.com/Cqprqxjb How can I implement your advice there?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ubuntu: Touchpad right click stops working after Ubuntu 18.04 install - Dell Support](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln316799/ubuntu-touchpad-right-click-stops-working-after-ubuntu-18-04-install?lang=en):

> ### Did the right click on your touchpad stop working after installing Ubuntu 18.04?
>
> > After installing Ubuntu 18.04, the touchpad right click may not function. This is not an issue with the operating system or your touchpad.
> >     Gnome defaults to the Mac touchpad behavior where the entire touchpad is a single button, and in order to right click you use two fingers to click instead of just one.

Alternatively, this same webpage has instructions to restore standard touchpad functions (e.g. middle-click, right-click):

> Open terminal and run:
>
> ```
> sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas
> ```
>
> #### OR
>
> 1. Install GNOME Tweak tool using
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
>    ```
> 2. Run GNOME Tweaks using
>
>    ```
>    gnome-tweaks
>    ```
> 3. Go to keyboard and mouse and look for the Mouse click emulation section. Check the Area checkbox to enable middle and right click.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Hold the right touchpad button for 2 seconds and if will work.