# Only the primary button of my touchpad is working

Tags: touchpad, dell, 17.04

Only the primary button of my touchpad is working.

If the primary button is selected as left only the left button is working, and if the right button is selected as primary button both the button acts as right button.

I've tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957099/dell-vostro-3568-model-ubuntu-17-04-touch-pad-left-and-right-click-behaving-same/957831#957831) to a similar question, but the problem persists.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66772/discussion-on-question-by-madhu-anand-only-the-primary-button-of-my-touchpad-is).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to explore properties of your touchpad in `dconf-editor`. 
**Don't run it as sudo, because these settings must affect only user settings.**

Navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/`

Please take a screenshot before doing modifications, so you can revert then in case of some of then cause any misconfiguration.

Follow instructions on this app. Feel free to tryout!